# Difference in behavior between Box<T> and RefCell<T> constructors

Tags: rust

In Rust 1.36, the following compiles:

```
let arr = [0 as u8; 30];
let buf: Box<[u8]> = Box::new(arr);
```

but this one fails, with the error: `expected slice, found array of 30 elements` referring to the undermarked code:

```
let arr = [0 as u8; 30];
let buf: RefCell<[u8]> = RefCell::new(arr);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone explain why the behavior is different? Both `RefCell` and `Box` constrain T as `<T: ?Sized>`.

Comment: @trentcl that does seem likely to be the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Box<T>` implements [the trait `CoerceUnsized<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) which allows a coercion from `Box<T>` to `Box<U>` whenever `T` implements [the trait `Unsize<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html). Intuitively, `T` implements `Unsize<U>` if `U` is the "unsized" version of `T`. For example, `[T; N]` implements `Unsize<[T]>` and `T` implements `Unsize<dyn Trait>` when `T` implements `Trait`.

```
impl<T, U> CoerceUnsized<Box<U>> for Box<T> where
    T: Unsize<U> + ?Sized,
    U: ?Sized,
```

`RefCell<T>` also implements `CoerceUnsized<U>`, but has a much more limited implementation. It can only perform a coercion from `RefCell<T>` to `RefCell<U>` if `T` can already be coerced to `U`, which doesn't include `T: Unsize<U>`.

```
impl<T, U> CoerceUnsized<RefCell<U>> for RefCell<T> where
    T: CoerceUnsized<U>,
```

The reason here is that the coercion behind `CoerceUnsized<U>` should always be behind a pointer. This applies with `Box<T>`, but not with `RefCell<T>`. `RefCell<T>`, despite being called **Ref**Cell, actually holds its data directly. `RefCell<T>` has the field `value: UnsafeCell<T>` and `UnsafeCell<T>` just has a single field `value: T`. There's no indirection going on here.

As it happens, the rules for `Unsize<U>` do allow `RefCell<T>: Unsize<RefCell<U>>` when `T: Unsize<U>`, so we can coerce between them if we hide behind a pointer.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let _: &mut RefCell<[u8]> = &mut RefCell::new([0; 30]);
}
```

Other (smart) pointers would work here too. `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>`, etc. [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=302ddfc09937754e5d0ce2bcd58b1102)